# Increment primary key/unique value on column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, primary-key, unique

My goal is to increment of +7 a primary key value into a table in MySQL db.

Tablename = table, Primary key = id

Example:

```
id   name   surname
1    John   Doe
2    Mary   McCain
3    Sam    Smith
4    Roy    Jenson
```

I need to turn it into

```
id   name   surname
8    John   Doe
9    Mary   McCain
10   Sam    Smith
11   Roy    Jenson
```

So that I can insert 7 more rows before the existing ones.

I tried:

```
 UPDATE table SET id = id + 7
```

But I get the error:

```
 Failed to execute SQL : SQL UPDATE table SET id = id + 7 failed : Duplicate entry '2' for key 1
```

Honestly I really don't know how to fix this, also because I have more than 122,000 entries in that table and it would take several days if not several weeks to update them one by one by hand.

Comment: What is the reason to change `Id` of the objects?

Answer (score 16):

Just add `ORDER BY ID DESC` at the end of the update query:

```
UPDATE table SET id = id + 7 ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74ded6/1)

Try to remove `ORDER BY` in the given SQLFiddle, you will get the same error.

#### Please take the backup before doing so.

---

If you are trying to subtract then you need to use `ASC` instead of `DESC` in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
UPDATE table SET id = id - 7 ORDER BY ID ASC;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7da112/1)

Comment: Yes, this makes sense... If you begin with lowest id and increase it there may have already been element with such ID unlike with your approach.

Comment: @Cthulhu - Yeah. And `ASC` for [the subtraction](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0174/1).

Comment: You can't sit on someone's lap when you are moving over seats! Let the last person do it first.